# How to point to another List

Tags: list, sharepoint

List 1

```
id  Name
12  Florida
1   California
3   Texas
```

List 2

```
id  p_id    Name
1   12      Miami
2   12      Orlando
3   3       Houston
4   3       Dallas
5   3       San Antonio
6   1       Los Angeles
7   12      Tallahassee
```

How can I create a new view for `List 1`, so when the `Name`(currently, link to edit the item) is clicked or create a new column, it will go to `List 2` and only display the rows which is the `id` from `List 1`

Comment: Sounds like a related list web part will do what you want, are you familiar with that?

Comment: Is it a regular webpart? I wanted to keep the list as is, as it has the sorting/filtering OTB so I don't have to recreate it. I can use a lookup column but is that something do-able?

Comment: Yes it is, I just posted details in my answer. Let me know if this is not what you are looking for, but it sounds like it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint provides an OOTB way to show related items between 2 lists, as long as the list has a lookup column to the other list.

For example, I have a list called "Testing" here that just stores some dummy data and urls. [image]

I have another list here , "TestLookup" that has a lookup column to my "Testing list. [image]

I have inserted a related list web part, on my "Testing" list Display form, so that when I click an item in "Testing" list, it shows all the items in "TestLookup" that are linked to it. 
[image]

To accomplish this:

1. Navigate to the Display Form page of the list you are wanting to add
   the Web Part to.
2. Click on Settings gear icon, then Edit Page.
3. At the top, you should see Insert, click on that.
4. Click the Related List drop down. SharePoint will automatically show you all the lists that are linked to this one. Select the list you want, and that's it.

Comment: I created both list and the child list sees a dropdown of the items  from the parent list. I clicked on Display Form Page on the parent list but the Insert Related List is disabled for some reason.I can create a new page and insert the parent list and I see the child list for relationship but when I add it, nothing happens.

Comment: Nevermind I got it... but I used another article to do so. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I saw that if I go to the "Web Part" tab - the control is disabled (not sure why). But if I go to the "Insert" tab - the option was there. Glad you were able to figure it out.